# InvalidToken cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, cryptography

Although similar type of question have been asked previously, but no answer seems to work for me.

I have used `cryptography` library to encrypt a string and then save that encrypted string in MySQL database. Then I have fetched the encrypted string from database and tried to decrypt it but it shows below error. The reason for error is that stored `fernet_key` always generates new encrypted string of same raw string in every run of .py file. For eg:

If I have given "prakash" as raw string then `fernet_key` will encrypt it in different strings on every run of the program. How to change this so that `fernet_key` will only generate a single encrypted string for every unique raw string?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 102, in _get_unverified_token_data
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (1) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/OneDrive/Desktop/FYP/fyp/dummy.py", line 696, in <module>
    print(f.decrypt(bytes(passwdnw[0][0], "utf-8")))
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 104, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

In order to run the below code, you have to install libraries like `mysql-connector`, `cryptography`

My code:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64, pickle
import mysql.connector as db

# This part of code is only used once for generating a specific key
# key is generated
fernet_key = Fernet.generate_key()
file = open("key.key", "wb")  # Open the file as wb to write bytes
file.write(fernet_key)  # The key is type bytes still
file.close()

file = open("key.key", "rb")  # Open the file as wb to read bytes
fernet_key = file.read()  # The key will be type bytes
file.close()

name = "Prakash"

f = Fernet(fernet_key)
encrypted = f.encrypt(name.encode())


try:
    conn = db.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("create database enc")
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
except:
    pass

conn = db.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="enc")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("create table if not exists encod(pwd varchar(50), encpass varchar(250))")
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()


conn = db.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="enc")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into encod(pwd, encpass) values(%s,%s)", (name, encrypted))
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()


conn = db.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="enc")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select encpass from encod")
passwdnw = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

print(name)
print(encrypted)
print(passwdnw[0][0])
```

Output:

```
Prakash
b'gAAAAABgZTs_Oyt5Ea5pboOKF2QRF8MRdhbFx5O9QidYcZu_D8zmOQK0ESwGYErfYXm9Cc7z9x_wk8uHYkr99C92agXfGQq1gA=='
b'gAAAAABgZTnhucw-49tuPVKfA-R6J-as3XEiDbASOb1wS3z4XCOlUlY8TGfnXZjDCwO8yEghqVH4w9CEqBenBJiwtXx3zUuJZA=='
```

As you can see there are 2 different encrypted form of same string, the first one changes on every run whereas second one remains same since it is fetched from database.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the reply, it seems MySQL converts byte to string while storing the data which results in losing the timestamp associated with fernet key

Comment: The timestamp is not the only reason for a different token for each encryption. Fernet uses AES/CBC and generates a random IV for each encryption, resulting in a different ciphertext and therefore tag for the same plaintext and key. This is an intrinsic (and therefore not changeable) property. However, this does not cause decryption to fail. Maybe token and key simply do not belong together during decryption.